# running out of drive space. Which files to move?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, disk, disk-usage

I installed ubuntu on a spare laptop and made the mistake of only partitioning 5 gigs for the install. i am already down to about 800 megs of free space. This install is only for learning cmds and general linux familiarity so i don't anticipate storing large files on it. But  Lately when i try to install ubuntu updates i dont have enough space to install them.  I have deleted downloads etc and other small files but i dont know what else i can remove safely.  I will be installing more ubuntu packages obviously so i need more space.

Any suggestions besides reinstalling the OS?

here is updated question with add'l disc info mentioned by N0rbert:

yes i ran the get clean apt first

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8146588       0   8146588   0% /dev
tmpfs            1634732    9660   1625072   1% /run
/dev/sda8        5122108 4020056    822144  84% /
tmpfs            8173656       0   8173656   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8173656       0   8173656   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2         262144   32664    229480  13% /boot/efi
tmpfs            1634728      12   1634716   1% /run/user/1000\

lsblk:
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  1000M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0  1000M  0 part
├─sda4   8:4    0   128M  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0 891.9G  0 part
├─sda6   8:6    0    20G  0 part
├─sda7   8:7    0  12.3G  0 part
└─sda8   8:8    0     5G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1 348.8M  0 rom
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you also have the option to re-partition your drive (using [GParted](https://gparted.org/), or similar). That might be easier in the longer term, rather than monitoring downloaded files, cached packages, etc.

Comment: Or even better just resize it and make it larger with gparted, be sure space at the end is empty space, you might have to move around some stuff. I would start by doing this in windows and make sure you don't overwrite any of that.

Comment: Open Nautilus (file manager) and empty your trash.

Comment: Please update your question with `df -h; lsblk`. Did you tried to clean APT cache with `sudo apt-get clean`?

Comment: i looked into gparted but it seems more complicated than i assumed.  For instance i am trying to determine if a windows install disc is needed to resize a partition? i have asked this in the gparted forum.

Comment: The gparted app worked great.  burned the Live version to a CD then booted from it. Had to boot into RAM to get the gparted app to load but then it did the resize in about 20 minutes. Now i don't have to reinstall the OS.  Excellent suggestion. Thank you.